# python import global variables but calls functions

Tags: python

I hava two global variables in my python module:
load.py:

```
a = load_a()
b = load_b()
```

I want to import a in my test file:
test.py:

```
from load import a
```

However, i found that b is also called, `load_b()` is also called
and `load_b()` may cost a lot of time
so my question is how can I just load a but not call `load_b()` function

Comment: do you have a blank '__init__.py' file in that directory?

Comment: yes, i want to just load a, but not b, however, b is also interpreted and load_b() function called

Comment: This is all normal Python code that defines normal variables. What if you wanted to import just `b`, do you think `import` would skip over the `a = ...` line? That's not how it works…

Answer (score 0):

`import` always executes the module from top to bottom. Loading a specific variable name isn't possible without executing the module fully:

```
from load import a
```

is the equivalent of:

```
# test.py
import load
a = load.a
```

You can't just load part of a module, there are many rationales for this behavior. For instance, your `load_a` function may use global variables defined after or before `load_a` function:

```
def load_a(arg):
    if arg in table: 
        # do something here...

table = [1,2,3,4]
```

`load_a` can also possibly change global variables.

The builtin `__module__` name for function objects is associated with the module where the function is actually defined, even if you use `from ... import ...` statement:

```
>>> from load import a_load 
>>> a_load.__module__
'load'
```

However, You may test for flags to prevent the call to `load_b`, or you even might use decorators `@`, there are many workarounds for this case of course:

```
if flag_b
    b = load_b()
```

Comment: The workaround advice at the end is not really something you should ever do, you should rather rethink your module structure. The rest of the answer is great though.

Comment: @deceze I agree, especially if you have hundreds of such calls, you'll end up littering your code with such flags. It serves the purpose for a simple task though, but not very elegant. *Don't' take it as an advice, only a simplified workaround ;-)

Comment: @KemmyGuo For example, you might consider moving `b = load_b()` to another module to avoid the expensive call to `load_b` when importing your module.  Also restructuring can be achieved in your code, you can restructure your code so for example `load_b` gets called only when the module run as a script not when imported. However, in extreme scenarios where the function is extremely slow, you may consider recoding the function to optimize it. A function may call another function, it doesn't mean the caller is always slower than the callee, it could be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink your design. If the importing module wants to do some initialisation, it should have to do it. The imported module should only provide the tools:

```
import load
a = load.load_a()
```

That way your module will have less unintended side-effects and will be more testable.